# resetear Datepicker y select multiple con JQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, select, datepicker

Necesito resetar dos Datepicker y select multiple de Bootstrap cuando finalizo de hacer unos procesos en el formulario, pero no lo he logrado, como puedo hacer eso?

Mi codigo HTML es este:

```
<%--/*fecha inicial*/--%>
        <div class=" col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3"> 
            <label for="comment">Fecha Inicial:</label>
            <div class="input-group date">   
                <input class="form-control SoloNumeros" id="txtFechaI" onkeypress="setSoloNumeros()" placeholder="Seleccine una fecha"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
     <%--/*----------*/--%>
     <%--/*fecha final */--%>
        <div class=" col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-3">   
             <label for="comment">Fecha Final:</label>
            <div class="input-group date">   
                <input class="form-control SoloNumeros" id="txtFechaF" onkeypress="setSoloNumeros()" placeholder="Seleccine una fecha"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div> 
        </div>
     <%--/*----------*/--%>

 <%--/*analisis*/--%>  
        <div class=" col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xs-5"> 
           <label for="comment">Analisis:</label> 
            <div class="input-group">   
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></span>
                <select  class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="selAnalisis">                   
                    <option disabled="" selected="">--Seleccione Un Tipo de Analisis Primero--</option>                   
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <%--/*----------*/--%>
```

Como puedo hacerlo con JQuery?

Comment: Deberias de poner tu codigo jQuery tambien

Answer (score 0):

con `datepicker` en jquery lo haces de esta manera, cuando presiones el boton que hace la funcion ponle esta adicional

```
$("#boton_accion").click(function(){
     $("#txtFechaF").val('')
})
```

pero con el `select` no se me ocurre nada, pero si estas usando la libreria `select2` te sugiero esto

```
$("#select").select2({
    allowClear:true
})
```

esto te permite agregar una x para eliminar todo lo que tengas seleccionado, espero te haya servido mucho

Answer (score 0):

Para resetear el datePicker:

```
$('#txtFecha1').val("").datepicker("update");
```

Para resetear el select multiple:

```
$("#selAnalisis option:selected").prop("selected", false);
```

Comment: oK, Me funciona el reStar del datepicker, pero aun no consigo hacerlo para el select multiple... gracias por tu ayuda ! @alanfcm